# Best practice for writing multiple SQL queries

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database

I have `2 tables` which will update at the same time.

As a example an `employee table and a department table` with many to many relationship so when new employee add to the table his department(s) will get inserted in a tertiary table. for now I first insert part of employee details to employee table then get that employees ID and then combined it with his department details I insert them to employee-departments table.

for do this I currently use 3 separated SQL queries. I need to rollback the first insert(employee) if error occurred in last query`(employee-department)` or could not get last inserted employee. can I achieve this with my current queries `(delete on failure as another query)` or will it be more clean if I use a stored procedure to do the whole thing.

thanks in advance :)

Comment: what you have done so far?

Comment: I have done inserting part with 3 different queries. now looking into validating those inserts

Comment: Read about transactions. E.g. you can write a method and mark it as @Transactional (if you use Spring) to perform all your queries together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using JDBC directly from JSP? I hope not... In any case, Spring JDBC has some good helpers for JDBC. You'd want to use JdbcTemplate, and DataSourceTransactionManager.

Here's a simple example (don't expect it to compile, just to get you going...)

```
DataSource dataSource = getDataSourceFromSomewhere();
DataSourceTransactionManager tm = new DataSourceTransactionManager(dataSource);
JdbcTemplate jdbc = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
TransactionStatus tx = tm.getTransaction(new DefaultTransactionDefinition());

int update1 = jdbc.update("insert into employee...");
int employeeId = jdbc.queryForInt(select id from employee...");
int update2 = jdbc.update("insert into employee_department...");

if (employeeId > 0 && update2 > 0) 
    tm.commit(tx);
else
    tm.rollback(tx);
```

If you don't want to use Spring (or can't), plain old JDBC can do the same thing:

```
Connection conn = getConnectionFromSomewhere()
... do a bunch of work ...
if (work was successful)
    conn.commit();
else
    conn.rollback();
```

I think its much easier working with the Spring JDBC library than regular old JDBC though.

Comment: thank you for the answer. I'm using plain JDBC for this application and I found a solution from your answer and @StanislavL comment.

Comment: Excellent! Glad to hear it.

Answer (score 0):

use **PDO transactions**

> [PDO::beginTransaction()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.begintransaction.php) —  Initiates a transaction
>   [PDO::commit()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.commit.php) — Commits a transaction
>   [PDO::rollBack()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.rollback.php) — Rolls back a transaction

```
$dbh->beginTransaction();

/* Change the database schema and data */
//...your all queries
/* Recognize mistake and roll back changes */
$dbh->rollBack();
```

Comment: sorry I haven't added java tag before. can I do this with `Java` I have a `JSP` web application.?

Comment: you must write your complete specification in question.I have no experience with JSP